# Preferred way of supplying java.library.path in TeamCity SBT runner

Tags: sbt, teamcity

What is the preferred way of setting **java.library.path** when running tests using SBT runner in TeamCity?

Outside of TeamCity setting **-Djava.library.path=/path/to/lib** VM parameter works just fine. Doing a similar thing inside SBT administration screen in TeamCity does not seem to make TeamCity honor it.

Any ideas?

Thanks.